# Integrate a callback logic based library function into promise chain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, q

To handle promises I return and chain them with `.then()`. I must however use a third party library that expects a callback and that does not return a promise.

For clarity, a fake example:

```
person.sayHello()
    .then( response => introduceMyself() )
    .then( name => externalLibrary.storeAndGetInfo(name) )
    .then( info => saySomeInfo(info) )
    .catch( err => console.log(err) );

introduceMyself(){
   return asyncFunctionToGetAndSayMyName();
}

sayDomeInfo(info){
    console.log(info);
}
```

My problem is that `externalLibrary.storeAndGetInfo` expects these params:

```
storeAndGetInfo(string, callback(valueThatINeedForMyNextChainedFunction));
```

I have the feeling that I could wrap the external library function in a chainable function (one that returns a promise), and then use [the library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) `q` to defer and resolve the callback function, but then I'm stuck as I don't know to actually implement it. Or is there another way?

PS in case it makes a difference, this is in a `angularjs` app

Comment: For the AngularJS framework use [Angular's $q Library](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to make promises that are integrated with the AngularJS digest cycle. Promises from external libraries will cause subtle hard to debug problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your external library's call with a function that returns a a deferred promise:

```
function promisedStore (name) {
  var deferred = Q.defer(); //initialize deferred

  externalLibrary.storeAndGetInfo(name, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      deferred.reject(new Error(error)); //reject promise if error in cb
    } else {
      deferred.resolve(result); //resolve promise if no error in cb
    }
  });

  return deferred.promise; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! I was close, but not close enough :-) will accept in 7 minutes

Comment: For the AngularJS framework use the [AngularJS $q Library](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) to make promises that are integrated with the AngularJS digest cycle. Promises from external libraries will cause subtle hard to debug problems.